# Interop: struct member name conflict with c# keyword - event

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I'm working with access control devices (terminals). API is native.
To send data to device, I instantiate struct(given by API), change it to IntPtr with [Marshal.StructureToPtr] and then pass that pointer to API function.
Here is the struct I'm working with.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct NameOfTheStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    ushort[] event;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    ushort[] someName;
};
```

The problem is that the member name in given struct overlaps with [event] keyword. If I change member name I guess that the function call to the native api will fail.

Would this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
[ComAliasName("event")]
ushort[] eventName;
```

solve my problem ? Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@` to use keywords as identifiers:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
ushort[] @event;
```

From C#, you would then access this field like this:

```
yourInstance.@event
```

The `@` will not actually be part of the identifier though.

You can look it up in the C# specification under "2.4.2 Identifiers":

> The prefix “@” enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The
>   character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier
>   might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the
>   prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim
>   identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords
>   is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you, I use mostly books for learning language whenever I can, but don't remember seeing this rule... I guess it's about time to rtfm :) .

Answer (score 2):

Try putting @ in front of it:

```
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
 ushort[] @event;
```